# How to specify which Apple ID xCode should use for Product->Archive->Export

Tags: ios, xcode

Firstly, I'm using someone else's Mac to compile an app (long story).

Secondly, I'm an xCode n00b. Two Apple IDs are registered. One is disabled/broken but I don't want to just delete it (see 1st sentence).

When I try to export the app, after Product->Archive->Export, xCode (6.2) is using the wrong Apple ID. I simply need to be able to specify that the 2nd Apple ID must be used.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That apple id is drop down list. Once you click it, you will be able to select second one.

In case it doesn't show others you need to add new apple id at accounts.
If you are used correct bundle id, certificate and provision, it will automatically select the apple id.

If it is still not, go to View Accounts/Accounts/Add Apple ID(+)

This can be accessed xcode/Preferences/Accounts as well.

Comment: Thanks for responding, appreciate it! I can see both Apple IDs under Xcode Preferences->Accounts, I select the 2nd one, which I want to use, everything checks out fine under 'View Details'. I go Product->Archive->Export and get an error indicating that the 1st Apple ID's password is incorrect. I don't care about the 1st ID, I'm trying to use the 2nd ID.

Comment: That must be a problem of password change. You need to modify password correct or delete it. Otherwise, it will not work

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer as correct. It doesn't resolve my issue, but it makes the most sense.